# Monitor display settings on Lenovo Ideapad 330 15ICH

Tags: display, lenovo, monitor, ideapad

The monitor on a fresh Ubuntu 18.10 installation shows washed out colors and a weird color tint. When compared to other laptops the difference is very noticeable. Out of the box I can only adjust brightness, which does very little to solve the problem.

I've tried:

- $ xgamma -gamma x.x -> no effect
- $ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --gamma x.x:x.x:x.x -> it does change gamma values
- I've also installed Gnome Color Manager. I can change color profiles, but I don't see any effect, unless I apply the test profile.
- $ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full" -> no noticeable effect

Any advice?
Many thanks in advance!